# How to use scapy to capture traffic like wireshark?

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, scapy

I use Wireshark to capture the traffic for browsing a certain website and use ip.src and ip.dst to get correct traffic.

I'd like to do this programmatically using Scapy. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Using Scapy and its wonderful documentation, create a Python script.  In the script, define a function that will act as a callback handler for received packets and in the main portion of the script make use of the `sniff()` function:

```
 def packetReceived(packet):
      print("Packet received!")

 sniff(filter="host xx.xx.xx.xx and host xx.xx.xx.xx and tcp port 80", prn=packetReceived)
```

Obviously, change the BPF filter to match the hosts you're targeting.